Determining significant predictors for a dataset with the outcome variable
I am working on a dataset and trying to get the significant predictors? The dataset contains numeric and categorical variables and there is an outcome variable.
What would be the best approach? I am formulating hypotheses for some of the categorical variables and running Fisher's Exact and Chi-Square to determine statistical
significance. For numeric variables, I am reviewing the correlation matrix and running T-Tests to show difference.
Could someone vindicate these methods? An alternative would be factor analysis. However, the dataset is a combination of both numeric and categorical variables. Thanks.

Welcome ! What about a regression model ? If you want to select the most contributive features I would suggest any frequentist or Bayesian shrinkage method. I could surely provide some R code to illustrate how to fit these models.

Thanks! The outcome variable is dichotomous. I am a newbie. By frequentist, did you mention the methods I had suggested?

Without being too technical frequentist refers to methods working well with large sample sizes. The methods you mentioned are indeed frequentist approaches in most cases. They are however univariate missing the possible joint effect existing between your variables. I will produce a short example ASAP.
